# confusion with regard to return statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I am going over some tutorial codes for React Hooks. So I saw something like the following:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello, World!"), 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
};
```

What is the difference between

```
return () => clearTimeout(timer);
```

and

```
return clearTimeout(timer);
```

I can only see the top one returns a callback, and that is it. Need some help here. Thanks

Comment: "I can only see the top one returns a callback, and that is it." and thats exactly the difference.  You can return a 'cleanup' callback from a hook that will run after the hook's lifecycle - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Item 1, returns a function that, when executed, clears a timeout.  Item 2, clears the timeout right away, and returns undefined.  For useEffect, you want item 1, so that when the component is unmounted the returned function is executed and the timeout is cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return () => clearTimeout(timer);
```

This returns a *function* that, when called, invokes `clearTimeout`. In contrast, just `return clearTimeout(timer)` *immediately* invokes `clearTimeout` just before the effect callback ends.

An example outside of React might be more intuitive:

```js
const makeFn = () => {
  return () => console.log('logged');
};
const fn = makeFn();
button.addEventListener('click', fn);
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

```js
const makeFn = () => {
  return console.log('logged');
};
const fn = makeFn();
button.addEventListener('click', fn); // doesn't do anything on click
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

If you return a function inside the callback, the function will only be invoked when the caller (eg, React, or `addEventListener`) tells it to be invoked.

If you don't return a function but instead run the code immediately at the bottom of the callback, the code will only ever run at the end of the callback, just before control flow yields to the caller of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You returns a function at first one `return () => clearTimeout(timer);` that will be called at the cleanup. So `clearTimeout(timer);` will run at cleanup of the effect.

On the other hand, you are calling the function at the second one `return clearTimeout(timer);` immediately, so there will be nothing to do while cleanup.